# CSS is not supported after adding Lightning component to the salesforce1 app

Tags: salesforce1-app, lightning-aura-components

I have added the interface "flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes" but it is showing an error like
    "Failed to save undefined: No INTERFACE named markup://flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes found : "

please provide me your valuable suggestion.

thanks.

Comment: That interface is for the Lightning Application Builder, which isn't required to add to S1 Mobile, which is currently a pilot feature and has to be enable by requesting access through your Salesforce rep. And what does this have to do with CSS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the requirement is to add this to the Salesforce1 Mobile Appliction, there is no requirement to use the `implements="flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes"` interface. You can simply add the `force:appHostable` interface and create a Lightning Components tab.

Actually each can get you to having your component surfaced in Salesforce1 mobile. The difference is that for `flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes`, you are using a Lightning App Builder app that sits on a tab UI. This way a non-coder can use build with Lightning Components. But if you're comfortable living in the world of markup, direct-to-tab will do.

You can look at [this SFSE question](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/64068/how-to-add-a-lightning-component-to-salesforce1-navigation-menu/64071#64071) to see an example of this.

Comment: @user3583904 - if that answers your question, please flag it as correct (the green check mark), so it shows up as answered. Thanks!