# How to add a lightning component to salesforce1 navigation menu?

Tags: salesforce1-app, lightning-aura-components, lightning-apps

I have created a lightning component and I need to add it to salesforce1 app. I'm trying to add the lightning component through Lightning Component Tab. But the lightning component that I have created is not visible in the Lightning Component dropdown. How can we add lightning components to the salesforce1 app?

Comment: I am also facing the same issue. But it seems there is a issue logged around the same. Please find below link describing same issue,
http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/53796/lightning-component-not-displaying-on-salesforce1-menu

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to have the component implement the interface as follows:

```
<aura:component implements="force:appHostable" />
//...your code here
</aura:component>
```

This is what tells the platform that you wish to use it in the S1 mobile application.

You can find more about this in the [Lightning Components Developer guide](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/) in the section on [Adding Lightning Components to Salesforce1](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/aura_add_cmp_salesforce1.htm).

Comment: Hi Peter, how can we add <aura:application > in the S1 mobile application?

Answer (score 1):

Very helpful
It shows in web browser /one/one.app
But in actual device mobile app I do not get the component navigation options. Currently struggling with this.